# How to filter link?

Tags: filters

I've installed a plugin which displays a custom widget and I'm trying to add a simple filter to change the `target` attribute in a link from `_blank` to `self`.

This is the code that I'm trying to modify:

```
<?php
                        $link   = "<a href='{$affiliate_link}' 
rel='nofollow' target='_blank' class='wppr-bttn'>" . __( 
$instance['cwp_tp_buynow'], 'cwppos' ) . '</a>';
                    if ( ! empty( $instance['cwp_tp_buynow'] ) ) {
                        echo apply_filters( 
'wppr_widget_style1_buynow_link', $link, get_the_ID(), $affiliate_link, 
$instance['cwp_tp_buynow'] );
                    }

                        $link   = "<a href='{$review_link}' rel='nofollow' 
target='_blank' class='wppr-bttn'>" . __( $instance['cwp_tp_readreview'], 
'cwppos' ) . '</a>';
                    if ( ! empty( $instance['cwp_tp_readreview'] ) ) {
                        echo apply_filters( 
'wppr_widget_style1_readreview_link', $link, get_the_ID(), $review_link, 
$instance['cwp_tp_readreview'] );
                    }
                    ?>
```

The code displays 2 buttons. It's the second (read review) link that I want to modify.

I tried the following code but it caused my site to crash:

```
add_filter( 'wppr_widget_style1_readreview_link', 'review_link_custom' );

function review_link_custom( $link, get_the_ID(), $review_link, 
$instance['cwp_tp_readreview'] ) {
$link   = "<a href='{$review_link}' rel='nofollow' target='_self' 
class='wppr-bttn'>" . __( $instance['cwp_tp_readreview'], 'cwppos' ) . 
'</a>';
return $link;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invalid PHP (which should have been obvious from the PHP error log).

```
function review_link_custom( $link, get_the_ID(), $review_link, $instance['cwp_tp_readreview'] ) {
```

Functions can have neither other functions nor array+key as an argument, you can only specify the name for an argument passed. Also, when adding a filter you have to specify how many arguments are passed to it (default is 2 - you have 4, so it needs to be explicitly specified). Try something like this instead

```
add_filter( 'wppr_widget_style1_readreview_link', 'review_link_custom', 10, 4 );
function review_link_custom( $link, $id, $review_link, $cwp_tp_readreview ) {
    $link   = "<a href='{$review_link}' rel='nofollow' target='_self' class='wppr-bttn'>" . __( $cwp_tp_readreview, 'cwppos' ) . '</a>';
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working except the button text is missing.

Comment: @jrcollins Please see my update

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working perfectly now. Could you please explain how you get the `$cwp_tp_readreview` variable from `$instance['cwp_tp_readreview']` and the `$id` variable from `get_the_ID()`?

Comment: @jrcollins It is a bit difficult to explain for me here .. These are just names you assign, you could also say `function review_link_custom($foo, $bar, $baz, $hello)` and it would work. I find the official PHP doc helps alot, ie [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and [there](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)